How to use std::any to store an callable object
This code is failed with std::any_cast, how to make it work?
#include <any>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test
{
private:
    std::any cb_;

public:
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T cb)
    {
        cb_ = cb;
    }

    template <typename... T>
    void bar(T... arg)
    {
        std::any_cast<std::function<void(T...)>>(cb_)(arg...);
    }
};

void test(int a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}

int main()
{
    Test t1;
    t1.foo([](std::string s) { std::cout << s; });
    t1.bar("hello");

    Test t2;
    t2.foo(std::bind(test, std::placeholders::_1));
    t2.bar(2);
}

I tried use void* cb_; but got compile error.
Move comment to here to clarify:
The purpose of Test class is trying to provide 2 methods, the subscriber will call function foo to register a callable object which could be a lambda, std::function or the object returned by std::bind. Then the publisher will call bar on the same instance of Test to pushlish some message to the subscriber. I want to use the template to avoid define multiple callable object type. That's why I use std::any to store it.
In fact, it's trying to do something like Qt signals, but qt will use some pre processer to deal with emit slots signals key words. In this case, there is no pre processor. And if the arguments passed to  function Test::bar does not satisfy the callable object cb_, there should be a compile error.

replace std::any with std::function

why use std::bind ? it does not return a std::function (and a lambda is no std::function either)

what are you trying to achieve? The solution depends on that. The simple fix is to store a std::function in the std::any but I am not sure if that is what you want

@AhmedAEK std::function can only store fixed signature. You cannot have one std::function to store void(std::string) and void(int). They can replace the whole Test with std::function, then I agree

looks like a very bad design overall, anyway the wrapper needs to convert it into a std::function and remove all CV qualifiers from the std::function arguments before it attempts to store it into the std::any, even then the probability of the user calling it correctly on the first 3 tries is almost 0% , it very easy to mistype one of the arguments and get a runtime error since you have basically thrown the C++ type system out of the window (minus the duck-typing of other languages), i would recommend you use python instead.

@AhmedAEK The purpose of Test class is trying to provide 2 methods, the subscriber will call function foo to register a callable object which could be a lambda, std::function or the object returned by std::bind.  Then the publisher will call bar on the same instance of Test to pushlish some message to the subscriber. I want to use the template to avoid define multiple callable object type. That's why I use std::any to store it.

IMO whenever you think you need std::any... look at your design again.

Whatever type you put into a std::any, you need to pull the same thing (by type) out of the std::any to use it.  If you put in a lambda rabbit, you can't pull out a std::function lion.   q.v. std::any::type

std::any is pretty useless, see if you can rework your code using std::variant

@Gene std::any is not useless at all. If you consider it as equivalent to std::variant then yes, its useless, but it is more than that

please add details to the question, dont mention them only in comments. How is the publisher supposed to know what arguments to pass to the stored function?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai -- perhaps it's not completely useless, but taking into account that for years writing C++ I used it exactly zero times, I have to suspect it's utility is very close to zero. If you have any practical use case, I would like to hear.

You can only retrieve the same type from the std::any you stored before. Neither the return of std::bind nor the lambda are std::functions.
Also "hello" is not a std::string, which will cause the wrong argument type to be deduced.
The simple fix is to explicitly use the correct types:
Test t1;
t1.foo(std::function<void(std::string)>{[](std::string s) { std::cout << s; }});
t1.bar(std::string{"hello"});

Test t2;
t2.foo(std::function<void(int)>{std::bind(test, std::placeholders::_1)});
t2.bar(2);

Live Demo

Test::Foo should be changed to take a std::function<void(Args...)>, so class interface would be "correct".

Yes, it's working, but it needs to construct the std::function object explicitly with a long type definition. Is there any way to do that construction implicitly like the code snippet did?

@john what are you trying to achieve? In your example its not obvious why you use std::bind or std::function or std::any, hence I am unsure what to suggest

With CTAD, first case might be simplified to t1.foo(std::function{[](std::string s) { std::cout << s; }}); (and std::function might even be hidden inside the template function), but std::bind return type doesn't allow std::function's CTAD.

CTAD doesn't work with std::function in the general form. The signature needs to be provided.
